# Can i implement web form as View from MVC concept inside asp.net web API project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently building a VB.net web API project that is going to be used by computers, but after this project is finished, i'll proceed to extend the project to be able to be used as a mobile app as well.

Since MVC is included in the web API, my question is, can the user-interface be built using web forms instead of vbhtml? Is there a difference in function between those two besides the difference in extension(.aspx and .vbhtml)? Will it also work as a View from the MVC concept?

Comment: Why do you want to use Web Forms instead of Razor/MVC?

Comment: Maybe because there is a design view where i can add textbox,etc from the toolbox section.

Comment: Design view is not a good way to create a UI in the modern web. The HTML that is generated is difficult to manipulate. You're much better off learning HTML/CSS and using a proper framework for styling your application. That holds true whether you use Web Forms or MVC. But anyways, you can use Web Forms alongside MVC and Web API.